# ReverseSemaphore not working in python

Tags: python, multiprocessing, semaphore

I wanted to write my own ReverseSemaphore, but somehow it is not working!

```
from time import sleep
import multiprocessing

class ReverseSemaphore(object):

    def __init__(self, countTo):
        current = 0
        self.countTo = int(countTo)
        self._cur = None
        self.event = multiprocessing.Event()
        self.clear()
        self.lock = multiprocessing.RLock()

    def _dec(self):
        self.lock.acquire()
        self.current -= 1
        print("decreased to %s" % self.current)
        self.lock.release()

    def _inc(self):
        print("acq")
        self.lock.acquire()
        self.current += 1
        print("increased to %s" % self.current)
        self.lock.release()
        print("released")

    def clear(self):
        self.lock.acquire()
        self.event.clear()
        self.lock.release()

    def wait(self):
        self._inc()
        if self.current < self.countTo:
            print("current=%s, countTo=%s, waiting" % (self.current, self.countTo))
            self.clear()
            self.event.wait()
        else:
            self.event.set()

    def ready(self):
        self._dec()

def action(num, reverseSemaphore):
    print ("process %d started" % num)
    reverseSemaphore.wait()
    #do some working code but simulate with sleep for the example
    sleep(3)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    count = 2
    reverseSemaphore = ReverseSemaphore(count)
    for i in range(count):
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=action, args=(i, reverseSemaphore))
        p.start()
```

will give me this output:

```
thread 0 started
acq
increased to 1
released
current=1, countTo=2, waiting
thread 1 started
acq
increased to 1
released
current=1, countTo=2, waiting
```

Then I get a deadlock.... The problem here is, that I expected the Process 1 to increase the counter to 2 which should release both....
Why is my ReverseSemaphore.current increased to `1` instead of `2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since in different threads, `reverseSemaphore` is different which you can see from `id()` result. Like this:

```
...
def action(num, reverseSemaphore):
    print ("process %d started" % num)
    print ("id of reverseSemaphore in this thread is: %d" % id(reverseSemaphore))
    reverseSemaphore.wait()
    #do some working code but simulate with sleep for the example
    sleep(3)
...
```

OUTPUT:

```
process 1 started
id of reverseSemaphore in this thread is: 43735080
acq
increased to 1
released
current=1, countTo=2, waiting
process 0 started
id of reverseSemaphore in this thread is: 44521400
acq
increased to 1
released
current=1, countTo=2, waiting
```

As you can see, each `reverseSemaphore` object in its thread has its own attribute current. That's why in process 1, value of `current` doesn't increase to 2.

Here is a good instruction for you about communication between threads in Python. I'm sure you can find your answer in it.

http://pymotw.com/2/multiprocessing/communication.html

Hope my answer helps. :)

Comment: Right! I actually switched from threading to multiprocessing, where it would work. It was late and I completely missed that!